# I am as fast as lightning

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I am as fast as lightning and my pose is recognized around the World. Who am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are you referring to the sprinter Usain Bolt? He holds the WR in both the 100 and 200m so he is certainly pretty fast (for a human). The word lightning is also an allusion to his last name 'Bolt'. He also has a famous pose: https://www.herefordtimes.com/news/9860230.picture-gallery-can-you-strike-the-legendary-usain-bolt-pose/

Comment: You got it! Well done.